# Custom snippets / reusable components in divshot

Tags: divshot

Will it be possible to add our own HTML snippets / component to reuse from the components list? At the moment i use divshot to create my basic bootstrap layout. afterwards i insert a couple of child divs and html to the layout manually (these snippets also use custom css). Would be great if we could define our own snippets / components within divshot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Great suggestion! We do plan on offering custom HTML components and snippets eventually. In the meantime you'll need to continue using the HTML source editor.